# How to trigger a rule if a node has a certain Taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, rules, media

I'm trying to create a rule using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) that will apply a watermark to an image within a node (using the ImageCache Actions module) if that given node has a specific Taxonomy term. For example, nodes with the term "Video" will get a play button icon over their image.

Is there a way to add taxonomy terms as a condition in Rules? It seems like it would be a simple task but I can't seem to figure it out. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: A rule will trigger only after an event but here you do not have any event. you are having only the condition.

Comment: Could the event "before saving content" work?

Comment: may be you can try before and after both situation.

Comment: Its doable but it will be painful. Check out [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) to assist you if you need more advanced Rules logic. If I was you I would implement template_preprocess_node, check the value of the taxonomy term, and wrap image with a div that has a class on it, then style with CSS. And should you not rather try to switch out the image formatter with your Rules approach to a formatter that includes watermarking?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this, rather basic, rule (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format):

```
{ "rules_check_taxonomy_term" : {
    "LABEL" : "Check Taxonomy Term",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert" : [], "node_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_tags" } },
      { "list_contains" : { "list" : [ "node:field-tags" ], "item" : "21" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "A node containing the tag [node:field_tags] just got created or updated." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is what this rule does:

- Rules Event: After saving new content, After updating existing content
- Rules Conditions:

  - ***Entity has field*** "`field_tags`", which is the machine name of the term reference field I want to check for.
  - ***List contains item*** "node:field-tags" and with Taxonomy term identifier value "`21`" (which is the term id of the term I want to check in this Rules Condition).
- Rules Action: Show a message on the site (which is "*A node containing the tag [node:field_tags] just got created or updated.*" (with `[node:field_tags]` the actual term with term id = `21`).

What is crucial in the above rules example in the context of this question, are the 2 Rules Conditions.

Use the Rules UI to import the above rule in your site. Here are the tweaks you'll need to make it fit your case:

- Replace the Rules Event (if needed).
- Within the Rules Conditions, perform these changes:

  - replace the "node" entity with your entity.
  - replace the machine name of term reference "field_tags", and adapt the "term id" to fit your case (for the term "Video").
- Replace the Rules Action by whatever fits your case.